# Telerik RadChart in a Sharepoint 2010 webpart

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-foundation, telerik

Wondering if anyone can detail step by step how to use the Telerik RadChart control in a Sharepoint 2010 webpart.....what modifications need to be made to the web.config, etc.  The info on the site is for 2007 and the about the SafeControls seems to be wrong.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Sorry, per the [FAQ](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)  we do not accept questions about commercial, third-party products.  Instead, please ask your question using the vendor's support site.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably contact Telerik for help about this. This is outside the scope of this forum.

Answer (score 1):

You'll just need to add a `<%@ Register %>` tag for your Telerik component (assuming you're building a visual webpart) and to make sure it is installed on GAC.

That `<SafeControls />` entry is meant to register which *webparts* are trusted by your web application. Telerik doesn't contains webparts, so it doesn't need to be listed there.